# Can Rails’s ActiveMailer do anonymous email addresses like Craigslist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I have a Rails 7 marketplace app and I want to implement Craigslist-style emailing between users (with anonymized email addresses).

Can ActiveMailer handle this, or do I need a third party solution?